# Google Analytics incised of Facebook

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

i wanna put the google analytics inside of Facebook.
I use the static HTML and the FBML , and i put the code of Google Analytics in the page (the javascript). However i can't get any results in google analytics.

Can someone tell how can i resolve that issue ?

Comment: where exactly are you trying to get analytics? a page app or a canvas app? or are you talking about something else? please be more specific.

Comment: I wanna track the likes, comments, shares of my page in facebook. It's like a page of company ,not a page of app.

Comment: that´s not at all possible

Comment: So what alternatives i have to put the information that facebook provide me ? Can i export the facebook data and put in google analytics ?

Comment: use facebook insights

Comment: How can i get it ? Can you help me pls ?

Comment: if you are the owner of the page, just open the insights. not really that hard to find. > https://www.facebook.com/yourpage/insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably impossible. Facebook should provide their own analytics.

Reason, you can't have it is because facebook probably eliminates Javascript form the content you post for security reasons.

Start here:
https://www.facebook.com/help/336893449723054/

Comment: I know that facebook delete de javascript code. I wanna use something like FBML or static HTML. And track likes, shares or comments. I think that is possible. But i don't receive information from the code i put in facebook , that is my problem.

Comment: You just can't do that. HTML can't track anything, you need JS for that. If JS is filtered out, it's not going to work.

Comment: So, i just can use the analytics of facebook ?